# How can I compare two strings by more than just one character?

Tags: c, strcmp

So I want to compare two strings by more than just one character. I know how to compare two strings character by character, or just by character on an selected position but I'm not sure how to compare two string by more than one character? For example I want to compare two string by 3 last characters, how can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
if( strcmp(str1-1, str2-1)==0 && strcmp(str1-2, str2-2) ==0)
```

but it doesn't work. I'm taking two strings from the user with scanf function.

```
if( strcmp(str1, str2) ==0){
    printf("equal");
}else{
    printf("not");
```

Comment: What should the result if one or both of the strings have a length smaller than 3 characters?
For simplicity it is better to define that the last 3 characters of "yz" are "xyz" not equal. This is natural.
But even more important: The last 3 characters of "ab" and "ab" are NOT equal!

Comment: Do you mean, how to compare substrings of two strings? In the title you talk about one char, then in the actual text you ask about 3 chars.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the length of the strings, subtract 3 from that, and add that to the start of the string to get the index to start comparing. Also, make sure that you don't get a negative index if the length of the string is less than 3.

```
size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
size_t index1 = len1 >= 3 ? len1 - 3 : 0;
size_t len2 = strlen(str2);
size_t index2 = len2 >= 3 ? len2 - 3 : 0;

if (strcmp(str1 + index1, str2 + index2) == 0) {
    printf("equal\n");
} else {
    printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not such function in the standard, but you can roll your own, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int revcmp(const char *a, const char *b, size_t start)
{
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(a);
    if (len < start) {
        return 0;
    }
    a += len - start;
    len = strlen(b);
    if (len < start) {
        return 0;
    }
    b += len - start;
    return !strcmp(a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a = "abcxyz";
    char *b = "123xyz";

    printf("%d\n", revcmp(a, b, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You return 0 if one of the strings is smaller than the number of last characters you want compare. But strcmp returns 0 if the strings are equal!
So you might want to return a number unequal 0, if either string length is smaller than start = 3.

Comment: You're welcome. But with the inversion you inserted, revcmp behaves differently related to strcmp and its result. This may confuse the client of the function.
Please also notice that strncmp does not only result a boolean information, but a value which says how the strings are lexigraphical ordered.

Comment: @Mico I agree, OP may choose a better name for the function

Comment: @SirJoBlack: revcmp can not modify the strings because "read-only" pointers are passed to it: const char *.

Comment: @Mico Ok, Ok! I've deleted my comment ... :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine the string length of both strings.
The lengths must be bigger than the number of last characters you want compare.
With pointer arithmetic you can move to the positions where you want start your comparison:

```
int strlen1 = strlen(str1);
int strlen2 = strlen(str2);
const int LASTCMP = 3;
if (strlen1 >= LASTCMP && strlen2 >= LASTCMP 
   && strcmp(str1+strlen1-LASTCMP , str2+strlen2-LASTCMP ) == 0)
{
    printf("last %d characters are equal", LASTCMP);
}
else
{
    printf("not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare just certain number of chars, you can use [`strncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp).

If you want to compare *last 3 characters*, then you need to determine the index of 3rd last character of each strings, so you can start comparing from that. For that you need `strlen`.

Putting above together, and accounting for strings shorter than 3 chars:

```
int pos1 = strlen(str1) - 3;
int pos2 = strlen(str2) - 3;

if (pos1 >= 0 && pos2 >= 0 && strncmp(str1 + pos1, str2 + pos2, 3) == 0) {
   // last 3 chars of the strings match
}
```